# How to enable Camera on Windows tablet (SurfacePro) using javascript/Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, windows-8.1, sapui5

I'm working for a secure Client where Camera is disabled or not allowed onsite.

We have a requirement to take a picture from bespoke javascript/SAP UI5 application using Windows Surface Pro tablet and upload image into SAP DMS. However, Camera can be used from a mobile application to take a picture.Camera can only be allowed from this application and will be disabled otherwise.

I've checked Kaspel/Cordova APIs allows capturing picture on mobile device by triggering Camera on tablet. I can use these Camera API to capture the picture from device Camera.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html

However, the requirement is to first enable the camera to allow taking a picture and then disable camera before exiting the application. Could you please guide me how can I enable the Camera from the application if it is disabled.

Kindly suggest ?

Regards,
Umesh

Answer (score 0):

Whether an application has access to the camera is not the responsibility of the application, but should be configured in the MDM (mobile device management) environment. The MDM should support per-application policies to allow the camera to be used in your application, while camera-use by other applications should be restricted.

Note: When the MDM has secured the mobile device and restricted camera use, it shouldn't even be possible for an application to break through this security and switch the camera back on.